# Blank cells break script using onEdit()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote this script to enter data in a row by hitting enter to step through it's cells from left to right.

Code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
   var cell,
       newCell,
       col,
       sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

    col = sheet.getActiveCell();
    newCell =  col.getColumn();

    if (newCell == 7.0) {
       //Processed last column, move to column A
       cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
       cell = cell.offset(1, -6);
       sheet.setActiveSelection(cell);    
    } else {
       cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
       cell = cell.offset(0, 1);
       sheet.setActiveSelection(cell);
       }
}
```

It works until I get to a cell I need to leave blank. Hitting enter when leaving a cell blank does not trigger an onEdit() event. I can skip  a column that is always blank by adjusting the previous cells offset() method. However I cannot figure out a way to adjust for a cell that is sometimes blank and sometimes will contain data.

I know that if I just enter a space in the cell the script will work. I don't think having a space in a cell that looks blank will harm any of my sheets, but I really would like to solve this issue with code.

Thanks,  Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test the cell value for a space:

```
if (activeCell.getValue() === " ") {
```

There is no way for a trigger to detect when the Enter key was pressed without the cell being edited.  Pressing the spacebar, and then hitting Enter is probably the best option in this case.  If the active cell is found to have a space, you can immediately delete the space.

```
activeCell.setValue("");
```

### Full Code:

```
function runOnEnter() {
  var activeCell,cell,newCell,col,sheet;
  Logger.log('it ran oky')
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  col = activeCell.getColumn();

  if (activeCell.getValue() === " ") {//The active cell has one space
    Logger.log('it has a space')
    activeCell.setValue("");//Delete the space
    return;//quit
  }

  if (col == 7.0) {//If this is column 7
    cell = activeCell.offset(1, -6);
    sheet.setActiveSelection(cell);//move to column A
  } else {
    cell = activeCell.offset(0, 1);
    sheet.setActiveSelection(cell);
  }
}
```

Comment: I just discovered apps-script a week ago and am still trying to understand it, so please forgive my ignorance. How do I use your code along with my onEdit() function?

Comment: In the code editor, click the "Edit" menu, and then click "Current project's triggers."  Add a new trigger, and choose the function name from a drop down list.  The function name should be something other than "onEdit()"  The function name "onEdit()" is a *reserved word*  But the onEdit() function is a *simple* trigger which has fewer capabilities.  If you find that my answer solves your issue, you can click the big green check mark to mark it as correct.

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem and I learned about installable triggers which I had been meaning to understand. I did make on small change to your code. I commented out the return. With the return active the script would stop when it encountered a blank cell. With it commented out I can continue to enter data as needed.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.